# Recycler View Suddenly Reset Selected Card View's Background

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Selected Card View
[image: card view]

I just wanted to find a solution from the image above. Why is it everytime I scroll down then scroll up again the selected card view goes back to its normal background which is white. I've been looking for an answer for over 2 days. I hope someone can find a solution to my problem.

The RecyclerViewAdapter

```
public class RecyclerViewDataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewDataAdapter.ItemRowHolder> {

private ArrayList<SectionDataModel> dataList;
private Context mContext;

public RecyclerViewDataAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<SectionDataModel> dataList) {
    this.dataList = dataList;
    this.mContext = context;
}

@Override
public ItemRowHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    ItemRowHolder mh = new ItemRowHolder(v);
    return mh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ItemRowHolder itemRowHolder, int i) {

    final String sectionName = dataList.get(i).getHeaderTitle();

    ArrayList singleSectionItems = dataList.get(i).getAllItemsInSection();

        itemRowHolder.itemTitle.setText(sectionName);

        CandidateListDataAdapter itemListDataAdapter = new CandidateListDataAdapter(mContext, singleSectionItems);

        itemRowHolder.recycler_view_list.setHasFixedSize(true);
        itemRowHolder.recycler_view_list.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(mContext, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
        itemRowHolder.recycler_view_list.setAdapter(itemListDataAdapter);

        itemRowHolder.recycler_view_list.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return (null != dataList ? dataList.size() : 0);
}

public class ItemRowHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    protected TextView itemTitle;
    protected RecyclerView recycler_view_list;

    public ItemRowHolder(View view) {
        super(view);

        this.itemTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.itemTitle);
        this.recycler_view_list = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_list);
    }

}
```

}

The Candidate Adapter (Horizontal)

```
public class CandidateListDataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CandidateListDataAdapter.SingleItemRowHolder> {

private ArrayList<CandidateDetailModel> itemsList;
private Context mContext;

public CandidateListDataAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<CandidateDetailModel> itemsList) {
    this.itemsList = itemsList;
    this.mContext = context;
}

@Override
public SingleItemRowHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.candidate_card, null);
    SingleItemRowHolder mh = new SingleItemRowHolder(v);
    return mh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(SingleItemRowHolder holder, int i) {

    CandidateDetailModel candidate = itemsList.get(i);

    holder.name.setText(candidate.getName());
    holder.gender.setText(candidate.getGender());
    holder.dept.setText(candidate.getDept());
    holder.year.setText(String.valueOf(candidate.getYear()));

    if(holder.profile.getBorderWidth() == 3){
        holder.profile.setBorderColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        holder.profile.setBorderWidth(3);
    }

    Glide.with(mContext).load("http://192.168.43.87/Election/profile/"+candidate.getImgUrl())
            .thumbnail(0.5f)
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
            .dontAnimate()
            .placeholder(R.drawable.prof)
            .into(holder.profile);

   /* Glide.with(mContext)
            .load(feedItem.getImageURL())
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
            .centerCrop()
            .error(R.drawable.bg)
            .into(feedListRowHolder.thumbView);*/
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return (null != itemsList ? itemsList.size() : 0);
}

public class SingleItemRowHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    protected CircleImageView profile;
    protected LinearLayout layout;
    protected TextView name;
    protected TextView gender;
    protected TextView dept;
    protected TextView year;
    protected ImageView deptIcon;
    protected ImageView genderIcon;

    public SingleItemRowHolder(View view) {

        super(view);

        this.profile = (CircleImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.prof);
        this.layout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.card);
        this.name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.candName);
        this.gender = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.gender);
        this.dept = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.dept);
        this.year = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.year);
        this.deptIcon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.deptIcon);
        this.genderIcon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.genderIcon);

        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), name.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                profile.setBorderColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
                profile.setBorderWidth(3);
                layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#80cbc4"));
            }
        });


    }

}
```

Comment: That's how RecyclerView works actually recycling views. SHow your adapter code, ther is a problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a default color if your condition is not met.  See below.

```
if(holder.profile.getBorderWidth() == 3){
        holder.profile.setBorderColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        holder.profile.setBorderWidth(3);
    } else{
//Set views' color to a default color.
}
```